# Error with compile kotlin class extend java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have next java class:

```
public interface Callbacks {
     void onImagePickerError(Exception e, Library.ImageSource source, int type);

    void onImagePicked(File imageFile, Library.ImageSource source, int type);

    void onCanceled(Library.ImageSource source, int type);
}
```

and next abstract class extended interface:

```
public abstract class DefaultCallback implements Callbacks {

    @Override
    public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, Library.ImageSource source, int type) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(Library.ImageSource source, int type) {
    }
}
```

In my case need in one place extend this interface and use it when callback coming from outher library.

In my android kotlin code looks like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Library.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, callback)
    }

private val callback = object: Library.Callbacks {
    override fun onImagePicked(imageFile: File?, source: Library.ImageSource?, type: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onImagePickerError(e: Exception?, source: Library.ImageSource?, type: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onCanceled(source: Library.ImageSource?, type: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

It's nothing special. But in compile time i have error:

```
Error:(239, 28) Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onImagesPicked(@NonNull p0: (Mutable)List<File!>, p1: Library.ImageSource!, p2: Int): Unit defined in github.library.path.Library.Callbacks
Error:(240, 9) 'onImagePicked' overrides nothing
```

1) why error have incorrect method name - onImage**s**Picked

2) why this not compile?

I try this and it's worked!

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Library.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, object: DefaultCallback() {
            fun onImagePicked(imageFile: File?, source: Library.ImageSource?, type: Int) {
                log("emm") //not worked and method useless
            }

            override fun onImagesPicked(p0: List<File>, p1: Library.ImageSource, p2: Int) {
                photoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(p0[0])
                setUpPhoto()
                log("worked") //worked! how?
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: `does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onImagesPicked(@NonNull p0: (Mutable)List<File!>, ...)` - It seems the method should accept `List` argument, but you declared a `File` parameter: `imageFile: File?`.

Comment: first two methods - i'ts library code

Comment: What I'm saying is the method you declared doesn't match the method that's required. You need `override fun onImagesPicked(p0: List<File>, ...)`, not `override fun onImagesPicked(imageFile: File?, ...)`. That's why the method which logs `"worked"` works: it shares the same method signature as the method that is required, while your `onImagesPicked(imageFile: File?, ...)` does not match. You cannot simply change the parameter types & expect overriding to work.

Comment: It looks like the `Callbacks` interface that Kotlin is seeing is not the same `Callbacks` interface you're seeing in your editor. Do you need to rebuild something? Maybe your pom/gradle.build is out of date? Some dependency somewhere may need to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty obvious: your `private val callback` doesn't have method `onImagesPicked(p0: List<File>)`.

But there may be several causes of this error:

1. Kotlin sees some another `Callbacks` interface then `public interface Callbacks` which we see. It can be baecause of

   1. Typo in import
   2. Wrong import
   3. Another version of library
2. The code you've posted above is not completely up-to-date

Comment: you right - Another version of library. Invalidate Cache -> Restart -> Clean -> Rebuild help .